# D3.js force directed for database use doesn't work

Tags: javascript, d3.js

So I know there are links to using D3 forced directed diagram for databases but they don't work. The reason is the forced directed diagram takes two arrays: the nodes which can be identified by node id (easy enough to get fro a database) and the links which consist of source, target and value as [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045).

The problem is that the source and target refer to the position of the node in the node array and not the node id as stored as an index in the database. This is even more complicated because the array is zero based whereas database indexes are not.

You can see how it might get messy if you delete a node from the database..

So my question is, is there a way of making sure the source target ids refer to the database id rather than the node id that anyone knows of...?

Comment: You can add as many extra members as you like to the node data, why not add the database key?

Comment: When used as data for the source array, the array of links should be of the form `{sourceIndex, targetIndex, value}`. However, it is simple enough to have an array of `{sourceSystemId, targetSystemId, value}` and then run through the list of systems and when `sourceSystemId == d.id`, set `sourceSystemId = i`. This way the index becomes relative to the system itself and is not static. Perhaps this approach could work?

Comment: Hi JsBob- would you know how to do that in a rails controller or should I ask as a separate question?

Comment: You'd have to ask a separate question. Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9nnnrmv0/) showing what I mean using JavaScript, if that helps at all. If you try inserting dummy entries into the system array, the link array will still point to the proper systems by index. Similarly if you delete entries it will still point to the proper system. Note that if you delete a system that is linked to something then the link will still use the system id (as it will not match an index). You could use something like a flag to handle this behaviour.

Comment: I believe the links can also use pointers to the node objects instead of indices. But generally speaking, you just need to reprocess your link array to get it into the proper format, as @JSBob mentions.